# Calling gapi.auth.authorize() returns empty access_token

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client

After calling `gapi.auth.authorize()` and getting the access token on the server side by this command:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({ response_type: 'code', client_id: "client_id", immediate : false, access_type : 'offline', scope: "scopes", redirect_uri : "redirect_uri"} , handleAuth1);
```

I call it again to receive a token in the client side:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: "client_id", immediate : true, scope: "scopes"}, handleAuth2);
```

for some reason handleAuth2 gets a result with no access_token. In this case my app asks from the user to allow access for the second time. In this case Google show the "Have offline access" because of the new policy.

Can I get the offline and the online permissions at once?

**EDIT**: I fixed the issue by using the gapi.auth.signIn() as google added this new API. The trick is to first call the api with these parameters:

```
  <span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="loginFinished"
    data-clientid="808248997275-ol6kol8h23j018iug3d5odi9vhrja9j5.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-accesstype="offline"
    data-cookiepolicy="http://brif.us"
    data-scope="profile https://mail.google.com https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive">
  </span>
```

Using the accepted code generate the refresh token on the server side.
The next call should omit the offline line so the code should be:

```
  <span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="loginFinished"
    data-clientid="808248997275-ol6kol8h23j018iug3d5odi9vhrja9j5.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-cookiepolicy="http://brif.us"
    data-scope="profile https://mail.google.com https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive">
  </span>
```

Hope this helps someone...